# How can i remove the same code block in c#?

Tags: c#

my code is a removing that file and folder

but my code has a same block

so I want to remove the same block

for example my code is

```
void Sample(){
if(true)
{
     AAA();
     BBB();
}
if(false)
{
     AAA();
}
```

like this!.

so i want remove the duplication of AAA();

Comment: If you always call `AAA()` pull it outside of the `if`.

Comment: could you please provide a more meaningful code-sample? With `if(true)` and `if(false)` it´s hard to examine under which conditions the method should be executed (if not allways).

Comment: @HimBromBeere *always

Comment: Then just call the method before the if-statement. Was this really your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
void Sample(){
AAA();
if(true)
{
     BBB();
}
```

Comment: Man, I posted the answer earlier! :/

Comment: Sorry. It's a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since `AAA()` runs regardless of the condition, you can do this:

```
void Sample(){
    AAA();
    if(true)
    {
       BBB();
    }
}
```